# Candidates Tournament

Tags: contest-math

> Five players $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$ participated in a chess tournament. It is known that all of the participants ended with a different amount of points, and that when ordered by them, they end up $ABCDE$. However, when ordered by the number of victories they obtained, they are placed in reverse order $EDCBA$.
>
> For what $n$ could an analogous situation in a tournament with $n$ players happen?

#### My work so far:

$n=2$ – Impossible.

$n=3$ – Example:

[image: Example for n = 3.]

$n=5$ – Example:

[image: Example for n = 5.]

Comment: I'm sorry, but the english of this post is near impossible to understand.

Comment: If I understand correct, we have to construct a scenario that all players have a different number of points in a multiple-round-tournament. Moreover, the ranking by won games must be completely opposite to the ranking by points.

Comment: This would mean that the better a player was placed, the smaller (or at least not bigger) the number of won games is, which seems to be paradox at first sight.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, it is true

Comment: Maybe this exercise was made to show that candidate tournaments in this manner have major issues.

Comment: Please edit the problem so that it was clear